# Dark Souls 2: Heavy Build(Alonne Knight Captain Armour) which large weapon should I use?

Tags: dark-souls-2

So, I've got a Quality Build, in which I use the Alonne Knight Captain Armour, and have 50 strength, and 30 dexterity, I've also got enough Vitality to have 30% equip load, and am using the drangleic shield. I have the third dragon ring, royal soldier's ring +1, ring of steel protection +1, and the ring of blades +1.

I use the Blacksteel Katana when I need speedy attacks that I can roll out of. In my other hand I use the Craftsmen's Hammer for my main damage output, which I like because of the scaling, the axe moveset, and the strike damage. I've used the Craftsmen's Hammer for most of the game, but have noticed that its damage and reach isn't very good for large enemies with big weapons such as Mastodons.

I've decided that an upgrade is needed, but am torn between all the really large strength based Greatswords, UGreatswords, Greathammers, and Polearms. I would appreciate some advice on the matter.

What I want is a big weapon with large damage and good reach (greatsword length or more) that doesn't take twinkling titanite to upgrade, and isn't made from boss souls.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I'd like to address you that this isn't a forum where you ask for advice or personal opinions, that's why you are being downvoted. 
I would still like to answer you because I think it is a great game and you took effort to write a lot of text :)

Ok I see you are fairly new to the game, so I will answer shortly, because I encourage you to play further and discover stuff yourself, especially weapons. Try weapons, try hammers, greatsword, ultra greatsword...

An excellent ultra greatsword, is simply the [Greatsword](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Greatsword).
It has max scaling on strength and huge base damage, simple move-set...

But then again, try yourself, watch the stats, ask for opinions on a dark souls forum...